# Can Limit take limits of unknown functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, symbolic, assumptions

For example, when I input this

```
 f[0] = 0;
Limit[f[x], x -> 0]
```

, it does not output `0`.

Is there a way to get it to output `0` in this case?  For example, is there a way I can get Mathematica to assume `f` is continuous?

Comment: If `f`` is not continuous, the limit could be anything.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm wondering if there's a way to get it to assume f is continuous.

Comment: It is sort of a chicken and egg question.  To assume that the function is continuous in zero is the same as saying that both limits are zero.

Comment: I agree, but ultimately I would like to do something more complicated, for example if f and g are both C1 at 0 and g'[0] != 0, to take Limit[f[x]/g[x],x->0].

Is there no way to give mathematica the assumption functions are continuous?

Comment: For this f and g need not only be continuous, but also differentiable. And with d'Alambert's rule the limit is f'/g' . Therefore, if you know f'[0] and g'0] you know the limit.

Comment: Define `f /: Limit[f[z_], z_ -> 0, ___] := 0` then all limits at `0` are `0`. `{Limit[f[x], x -> 0], Limit[f[x], x -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"], Limit[f[x], x -> 0, Direction -> "FromBelow"], Limit[f[x], x -> 0, Direction -> "Reals"], Limit[f[x], x -> 0, Direction -> "TwoSided"], Limit[f[x], x -> 0, Direction -> 1], Limit[f[x], x -> 0, Direction -> -1], Limit[f[x], x -> 0, Direction -> "Complexes"]}`

Comment: Yes.  And we need f[0]=0, and g[0]=0, but regardless - I know how to do this on paper, but I would like for mathematica to compute such things for me.

Comment: @BobHanlon This does work, but it then fails if I try something like `Limit[2f[x],x->0]`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
Limit[f[x], x -> 0,Analytic->True]
(*f[0]*)
```

Unfortunately,this option does not work for multidimensional limits, but works for iterated limits, e.g.

```
Limit[g[x, y], {x -> 1, y -> 0}, Analytic -> True]
(* g[1,0]*)
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much.